# Noetherian and Artinian modules are direct sum of finitely many indecomposible modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This question was asked in my assignment on Algebraic Geometry and I need help in solving the problem. The question is related to Artinian and Noetherian Modules, I am not good at solving problem of this particular topic.

Question is : (a) Prove that every artinian module is a direct sum of finitely many indecomposible modules.

(b) Every Noetherian module is a direct sum of finitely many indecomposible modules.

Attempt: (a) and (b) appear to be similar. So, I am posting attempt of (a) only.Let V be an artinian module and it is not direct sum of finitely many indecomposible modules. WLOG, $V= V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $V_2$ is decomposible, which means that $V_2$ is non empty and $V_2= V_3\oplus V_4$. There are further cases now (1) $V_3$ and $V_4$ can be  decomposible or both indecomposible ;   So, I have a chain condition $V_3 \subseteq V_2
\subseteq V$ . Similar ascending chain can be built for (b).

But I don't know what my next step should be ?

Can you outline a proof?

Answer (score 1):

You may have seen the descending chain, but maybe you overlooked the obvious ascending chain you can get at the same time.

Let $V_0=V$ and $V'_0=\{0\}$. Suppose $V$ is not a finite sum of indecomposables. Then we can recursively define $V_n$ and $V'_n$ by looking at a proper decomposition $V_{n-1}=A\oplus B$ and setting $V_n$ to be one of $A$ or $B$ that is not a finite sum of indecomposables, and setting $V'_n$ to be the sum of $V'_{n-1}$ and the one of $A$ or $B$ that *wasn't* selected.

Now: look for yourself what the properties of $\{V_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ and $\{V'_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ are!  The answer should be clear now.

The moral of the story is that infinite sequences of summands are going to produce both infinitely increasing and infinitely decreasing sequences of modules.

Comment: I think $V_i$ will be sum of indecomposables but $V_n '$ will not be sum of indecomposables. Am I right? But how does it proves what I want to prove? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Jimmy it shows that if the module is not a finite sum of indecomposables, then it had an infinitely descending chain and an infinitely ascending chain.  Who cares if $V_n$ or $V’_n$ is a sum of indecomposables or not? This is helpful because it establishes both contrapositive versions of the questions asked.